# Add claims to a UserPrincipal's request in dotnet core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I've done something similar to this a few years ago but can't find my code for this and can't remember how I did it!

I have a request coming in that is already authenticated but the token doesn't contain a specific claim that I require. Using middleware, I want to read the user id in the token (that already exists) and add an additional claim to the `UserPrincipal` from an external source based on that user id. NOTE that I don't want to manipulate the token to be sent back, it's just in the context of the api.

I want to do this so that my controller has access to this claim without having to explicitly request it, it should be present to begin with.

I believe I created some middleware that adds the claim but I can't see any examples related to adding a claim, when searching it's more related to updating claims in the actual token sent back which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

To add claims to user after authentication, the preferred way for .NET Core 2.x is to use [IClaimsTransformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.iclaimstransformation?view=aspnetcore-2.2) who has a single method `TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal)`.

1.Create a `CustomClaimsTransformer`

```
public class CustomClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public CustomClaimsTransformer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {

            var accesToken = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            // get user id from token 
            //...
            //add claims here 
            ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim("type-x","value-x"));

        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
}
```

2.Register it in ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, CustomClaimsTransformer>();
        //...
    }
```